# Using $row result in a variable name

Tags: php, variables, pdo, foreach

contID from my db just gives a number, that number i want to put on the end of a varible, tried it like this but it gives a blank page

if i take the

```
"" . $row['contID'] . ""
```

out its fine and the page loads fine, so i know its the wrong way to do it but i cant think of how to do it any other way, heres the code...

```
$object = new ConnectToDB();
$result = $object->getMarks($user,$ksGet);

foreach($result as $row){

    $marks"" . $row['contID'] . "" = "" . $row['mark'] . "/5";
}
```

the result from the db will give 7 rows the contID will be a number between 1 and 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an array is a much smarter idea than variable variables

```
$marks=array();
foreach($result as $row){

    $marks[{$row['contID']}]  =  $row['mark'] . "/5";
}
```

Comment: how do i echo that out, I'm guessing `$marks[1]` etc ?

Comment: don't guess, just try it